# Import appcompat-v7 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

I've tried to add the appcompat-v7 library for chaning the hint-color of the search bar. However I couldn't make it work. Any idea? This is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.+'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:library:2.5.2'
    compile files('libs/TestFlightLib.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'

    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

}

Any idea on how to make it work? Now it works gradle-side.. but it doesn't compile:

Error code: 139

```
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:cisalpina:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:cisalpina:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:cisalpina:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:cisalpina:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:cisalpina:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71901Library UP-TO-DATE
:cisalpina:prepareDebugDependencies
:cisalpina:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:cisalpina:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:cisalpina:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:cisalpina:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:cisalpina:mergeDebugResources
:cisalpina:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:cisalpina:processDebugResources FAILED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was a style not used by a resource. Deleting it will make everything work correctly.